# Making IPTVCore to work

Tags: java, android, eclipse, iptv

I am new to android and java development although I am an expert with IPTV and I have made the biggest Greek and Cyprus IPTV but since there is a lack of Greek IPTV android apps I decided to make one application.I found IPTVCore on playstore which is made by the developer of the IPTV app.In the description it has a link on an app that uses iptv core [github](https://github.com/AlexanderSofronov/iptv.example)

I downloaded the zip changed the icons and renamed the files. In MainActivity.java I removed the first comments and added my playlist url and changed package name.
I have android studio and eclipse with android addons.

How to make it an apk?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean to simply be able to load it onto a devices to test then both Eclipse and Studio will allow you do this when you elect 'Run' and have a device attached via the USB (with USB debugging enabled). This will actually install the apk on your device so you can test it.

If you mean actually making the apk available for others (via the play store for example) then you should look and the Android publishing documentation:

- http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/publishing_overview.html

In very broad terms, you develop the app, build it, test it etc and then when it is ready for release you build it for release (remove all debug code, test data etc), sign the app, and release it via a marketplace like Play Store, or avi email or your own web site.

One important thing to remember is to version the app properly - the is important for all the obvious reasons (users or support wanting to know the version) but also because the marketplace update mechanisms may use it to check what versions can be updated etc.

**Update** - answering the question in the comment below:

There are two approaches suggested in the Readme file with the project:

> To build you custom IPTV app you can do one of the following:
>
> Clone iptv.example project, change app name, launcher icon, and
>   package name. 
>   Blockquote
>
> Create new Android project with empty activity and use
>   the code from MainActivity.java

The second one might actually be simpler for you if you know how to create a simple Android project - just do that and then replace the MainActivity code in the newly created project with the code in the MainActivity file (the only java source file) in the githib project you have downloaded.

Comment: What I didn't understand is: After I download the zip from github and extract it how to import it on android studio